# Conditional key and value code optimization

Tags: php, arrays, stripe-payments

is there a better way of writing this code? Stipe doesn't accept the "starting_after" key to be blank, therefore, I first need to check if the "startingAfter" variable is being posted. I feel like there's a better way to do this, but don't know how.

```
<?php
$startingAfter = $_POST['startingAfter'];
$itemsToDisplay = 10;

require_once('../modules/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/init.php');

$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_xxx');

switch ($startingAfter) {
    case false:
        $customers = $stripe->charges->all([
            'limit' => $itemsToDisplay,
        ]);
        break;

    case true:
        $customers = $stripe->charges->all([
            'limit' => $itemsToDisplay,
            'starting_after' => $startingAfter,
        ]);
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: `$customers = $stripe->charges->all(['limit' => $itemsToDisplay] + (!empty( $startingAfter) ? ['starting_after' => $startingAfter] : []));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what about old plain `if`:

```
if( !empty( $startingAfter) ) ) {
    $customers = $stripe->charges->all([
        'limit' => $itemsToDisplay,
    ]);
} else {
    $customers = $stripe->charges->all([
        'limit' => $itemsToDisplay,
        'starting_after' => $startingAfter,
    ]);
}
```

But in my opinion the best way is something like:

```
$params = [ 'limit' => $itemsToDisplay ];

if( !empty( $startingAfter ) )
    $params['starting_after'] = $startingAfter;

$customers = $stripe->charges->all($params);
```

If you don't like extra variables, like one-liners and love bringing pain, here's the choice of yours:

```
$customers = $stripe->charges->all(array_merge(
    ['limit' => $itemsToDisplay], 
    empty($startingAfter)
        ? []
        : [ 'starting_after' => $startingAfter ]
));
```